# Почему к данному классу я не могу обратиться в классе Form1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, чтобы я мог работать с этим классом и его было видно в классе Form1?

Comment: оформите код текстом.

Answer (score -1):

Так как в `Class1` нету нестатических свойств, хранящих состояние экземпляра, то можно все методы объявить как `public static`, и они будут доступны из `Form1` через `Class1.dead()` и `Class1.check()`.

Если в `Class1` все же нужно хранить состояние, которое изменяется вызовом публичных методов, тогда нужно всего лишь в `Form1` объявить свойство или переменную типа `Class1` и задать ему значение - `MyProperty = new Class1()`. Тогда можно будет сделать так: `MyProperty.check()`.